# Simple model to predict with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm very new to tensorflow and I'm trying to figure out some tricks for future implementation.

I have a dataset consisting of three column, a, b and c. I'm trying to create a model which can predict c from a and b. By construction of the data, it is known that c=b/a.
I want to create a model which can capture the relation between the three columns s.t. it can be added to future models. This is what I have tried:

```
normalizer = tf.keras.layers.Normalization(axis=-1)
tfd = tfp.distributions
model=tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(normalizer)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=10,activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1))
```

Where the model has been fitted to a train set and tested on a seperate test set.

How can I create a model which can for example cross divide all columns with eachother and optimize through such a layer.

Comment: What is your question? Seems to be missing here.

Comment: IMO you should follow [the introduction to keras](https://keras.io/getting_started/intro_to_keras_for_engineers/) for the implementation. Just follow it step-by-step and you'll understand how to build a training loop and feed it your data.

Comment: A neural network can't compute the inverse of data directly because it is not linear but yes you can use a hidden layer with non-linear activation as you are doing. Maybe increasing the number of layer or increasing the latent space can be necessary.